# Do we live in a cosmic void?

Tags: galaxy

Why is it thought that we live in a [void](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_(astronomy)), when there are so many galaxies around the Milky Way? There are galaxies close by and also far away, so where do they see a void that we are in?

Comment: Have a look at the papers referenced in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KBC_Void) (the first four in particular).

Answer (score 5):

A "void" is not a complete absence of galaxies. It is an "underdensity".

It is suggested that in a vast vast vast vast (please feel free to add some more "vasts") region of space around our galaxy, there are fewer galaxy clusters than would be expected by random chance. It is suggested that the milky way, the Andromeda Galaxy, and the Virgo cluster are all in this region in which there are fewer galaxies than average for the universe.

That there are galaxies in a local group does not contradict this hypothesis. The claim is rather that "there are fewer large galaxy clusters within 300 megaparsecs than expected".  This does not mean there are *no* galaxies within 300 megaparsecs, only that there are fewer than would be expected.

Answer (score 5):

We are not living in a galactic void, but rather along a filament/surface of clusters running roughly between the Perseus supercluster and the Virgo/Laniakea supercluster. We are however living near the edge of the [Local Void](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Void).

[image: 2D projection of nearby clusters]

Comment: Note that the "void" discussed as the "KBC Void" is an order of magnitude or two bigger than the diagrams:  with a radius of 300 Mpc.  The "local void" is well established, the KBC void is more speculative.

Comment: @JamesK - It was not clear from the question that it was about the speculative term.